# Cron expression to run on different days for different months

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I need a `cron` expression for the following situation:

I want to run a schedule on midnight on every first day of every month; but march month should be an exception for that. For march, it should run on 15th of march.

Comment: Edited the tags appropriately

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Your question is not very likely to be answered by someone. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions and [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) what's the reason for.

Comment: @Chris Cooney  Cron jobs are used in java using Quartz library for Scheduling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with one expression, but two should be ok

```
0 0 1  1,2,4-12 * expr
0 0 15 3        * expr
```

i.e. the first expression runs for all months other than March. The second for March only.

Alternatively, you could specify that your script runs on the 1st *and* 15th, and your script could check which day is valid given the month. That would give you one expression, but you're splitting the date analysis between cron and your script, and consequently I don't think that's a particularly good solution. It's worth bearing in mind for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. I have one more question, can i update the same scheduler with the another crone expression so that my requirement can be fulfilled.