# Cron expression for different days in different months

Tags: cron

I have a situation to run cron every midnight starting 20th April and ending at 18th Dec 2017.

I am looking for cron expression for it. With my limited knowledge in cron, I could figure out the following which is closest expression for this-

```
0 0 0 20/1 4-12 ? 2017
```

But this runs for whole of december and doesnt end at 18th. I am looking for a single cron expression itself(if its possible).

I did some research ([Cron expression to run on different days for different months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068181/cron-expression-to-run-on-different-days-for-different-months)) and it seems I may have to use two different scripts, one for April and another for rest of the days but as I said I am looking for a single cron. Is it possible?

Comment: what technology? linux cron?

Comment: Yeah, its in linux environment,

Comment: So the only you can do is to use workarounds, for example set your cron to run on the desirable months and inside script, check it's between this two dates.

Comment: Thanks, I will think of using two scripts. However, I am still open to the suggestions just out of curiosity. If someone knows a single cron for this, pls update this post. By the way, if it were Windows, would it have made any difference?

Comment: I think it is just cron limitiations. It's just how cron works. I'm working on separate language that will covers such cases like yours but it's not connected to any scheduler yet. You could look here: https://github.com/Puchaczov/TQL.RDL

Comment: Also, you could probably use Quartz.Net multiple calendars to achieve that

Comment: Thanks Puchacz for all your help...I am using two separate scripts for now.